# iOS Facebook SDK: Apprequests dialog doesn't show up

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to use the code provided in the tutorial [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/)

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSMutableDictionary* params = 
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just smashed %d friends! Can you beat it?", 3], @"message",
    nil];
    [appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:nil];
```

But when the execution hits the dialog:andParams:andDelegate method call, nothing happens. For a split second I can see a progress indicator spinning, but then it disappears and no apprequests dialog is shown. No error is reported, but nothing happens.
I also tried defining a delegate, but neither of it's callback methods get called.
I'm authenticated and the facebook session is valid at the time when I try to call this dialog. 
Has someone encountered anything like this? Are any special permissions needed when logging in to be able to see this dialog?

Comment: mee too,,, the dialog appear and then disappear suddenly!

Comment: can you please post here when you figure out the answer? I've been stuck with this for more than a week now. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was invoking the dialog from a UIAlertView event handler, so probably it was not on the UI thread, which caused the error. If I invoke the code above from an IBAction handler, everything works fine.

Comment: If you want to make it appear using the UIAlertView Delegate,,, then you can invoke the method responsible for showing the dialog throw an NSTimer class method 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval',,, its work for me